# How do you preserve expensive 100% silicon color match for your grout for long term?

Tags: silicone

I have ordered this
https://thefloorbox.ca/products/tec-accucolor-100-silicone-sealant-62052?sku=TA155909&gclid=Cj0KCQiAnuGNBhCPARIsACbnLzpoEyuM_5bzygLTP1_bkEqQWohaDt3gA0AzWMOuPeLW3wWmsAtulZ8aAlpWEALw_wcB
This matches the color of my grout and I need only like 16' at max of grout line to be filled with this

How do I store this for long term and how often do I need to re-silicone the corners of my shower? (trying to determine here what "long term" would mean

Comment: Silicone has a max shelf-life when unopened; read the tube. At some point it will cure inside the tube leaving you with a silicone baton. It will usually last longer than the printed shelf-life  if the tube is unopened so just test it before you use it in the future.

Comment: If you find out, you will make millions.  Long term about a few weeks after opening.

Comment: You buy what you need now. When you need to redo it, you buy more.

Comment: Forget it, silicone has a short shelf life.  Magic requires compromises...  Even worse, using silicone *after it's gone bad* seems successful at first but is a nightmare to clean up so you can try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Long term' for unopened, uncured silicone sealant is about 1 year.
That's its shelf life. Beyond that, you might get lucky for another month or 12, but time will be running against you. If you open it, you can measure the life in months or weeks.

Beyond that, there are companies who will make up on demand [at a price] any type of sealant to any colour, usually specified in Europe as an RAL colour - see [Wikipedia; RAL colour standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAL_colour_standard)
There is also the issue that any colour-match is very much dependent on the substrate, surface reflectivity & ambient lighting conditions, so you will never know how close it is until you actually see it in situ.

As to how long the first seal lasts, that's very variable - dependent on the surfaces it's sealing, amount of movement, physical interaction [scrub it like hell 3 times a week & you'll start to pull away the edges]. Call it somewhere between 18 months & 25 years… yes, it's that broad.

Comment: The original caulking in my shower surround lasted nearly 30 years. The replacement only a few months. Granted, I believe that tube had been in the garage well over a year, but my experience backs up your estimate.

Comment: I think, basically, cured silicone itself will outlast all of us - it's just the adhesion that may fail earlier.

Comment: +1 for bringing up the ambient lighting conditions. That gets left out a lot and now-a-days is so important with the different types of lighting. I know people who went back to incandescent because LEDs  changed the color of the room too much.